# Can't inherit two classes that inherit one interface

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, interface

I have 2 interfaces: `Socket` and `ListeningSocket`, and 2 classes: `BerkeleySocket` and `BerkeleyListeningSocket` that implement those interfaces.
There will be more socket types, now it's just an example.
The problem is `BerkeleyListeningSocket` inherits both of `BerkeleySocket` and `ListeingSocket`. It inherits `BerkeleySocket` to avoid coping of base socket method implementations and `ListeningSocket` to implement listening socket methods.
But both class `BerkeleySocket` and interface `ListeningSocket` inherits interface `Socket`, but `ListeningSocket` have not implemented it's pure virtual methods (in the example is Close method) unlike `BerkeleySocket`, so I can't create an object of `BerkeleyListeningSocket` because of error `unimplemented pure virtual method 'Close'`.
Example code that illustrates the problem:

```
// This is an example code, so there will be more methods.

// ----------------
// Interfaces
// ----------------

class Socket
{
 public:
  virtual ~Socket() = default;

  virtual void Close() = 0;
};

class ListeningSocket : public Socket
{
 public:
  virtual bool Listen(int max_connections) = 0;
};

// ----------------
// Implementations
// ----------------

// Implementation of base socket.
class BerkeleySocket : public Socket
{
 public:
  explicit BerkeleySocket(SOCKET s) : socket_(s) {}

  ~BerkeleySocket() override { closesocket(this->socket_); }

  void Close() override { closesocket(this->socket_); }

 protected:
  const SOCKET socket_;
};

// Listening socket implementation.
// Inherits BerkeleySocket to avoid coping code of implementation of base socket methods, such as Close.
// There will be more derivatives of BerkeleySocket, so I can't move Close method to BerkeleyListeningSocket.
// Implements ListeningSocket interface. But there is a problem.
// Both BerkeleySocket and ListeningSocket inherits Socket interface,
// so ListeningSocket have unimplemented method Close
// and I can't create an object of BerkeleyListeningSocket because of it.
class BerkeleyListeningSocket : public BerkeleySocket, public ListeningSocket
{
 public:
  explicit BerkeleyListeningSocket(SOCKET s) : BerkeleySocket(s) {}

  bool Listen(int max_connections) override { return listen(this->socket_, max_connections) != SOCKET_ERROR; }
};

int main() {
  // Error! Unimplemented pure virtual method Close.
  BerkeleyListeningSocket listening_socket(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP));

  return 0;
}
```

Hope for your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *It inherits BerkeleySocket to avoid coping of base socket method implementations* → this is a mistake in your design. It should implement the interface, but use the implementation (as a data member). — Well mistake might be a bit big of a word, there are valid reasons to do it like you did, just it's not necessarily the first thing that you should do.

Comment: `ListeningSocket` doesn't override `Close()`, so `Close()` is still pure virtual in `BerkeleyListeningSocket`. The obvious fix is to override `Close()` in `BerkeleyListeningSocket`, and in the override, call `BerkeleySocket::Close()`. Or, perhaps, make `Socket` a virtual base of `BerkeleySocket` and of `ListeningSocket`. It's not clear from the question whether this is appropriate.

Comment: I would not inherit `Socket` in `ListeningSocket`. In fact I would rename those interfaces to: `Closable` `Listener`. IMO you are placing to many things in single class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where you need [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) because with your code, `BerkeleyListeningSocket` inherits twice from `Socket` (once from  `BerkeleySocket` and once from `ListeningSocket`). In order to tell the compiler to "merge both `Socket` in one", you need to change your class definitions:

```
class ListeningSocket : public virtual Socket
{
// ...
};

class BerkeleySocket : public virtual Socket
{
//
};
```